# Here in need to Pass Employee ID to other functions to store as foreign key in other tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I need to pass Employee ID to other functions as foreign key in other tables.

This is my `submitEmployeeBasic` function I want to pass:

```
public function submitEmployeeBasic(Request $request)
    {
        $employee = new Employee;
        $employee->employee_code=$request->get('empl_code');
        $employee->employee_file_no=$request->get('empl_file_no');
        $employee->employee_name=$request->get('empl_full_name');
        $employee->employee_grade=$request->get('empl_grade');
        $employee->employee_work_site=$request->get('empl_work_site');

        $employee->employee_notes=$request->get('empl_notes');

        $employee->save();
        $emp_id = $employee->id;
        $this->getEmp($emp_id);
        return redirect(route('emplisiting'));

    }
```

This is my `store` function. I need to pass `$emp_id = $employee->id;` to this function.

```
public function saveEmployeePersonal(Request $request){
        $emp_personal = new EmployeePersonal;

        $emp_personal->employee_father_name=$request->get('empl_father_name');
        $emp_personal->employee_mother_name=$request->get('empl_mother_name');
        $emp_personal->employee_spouse_name=$request->get('empl_spouse_name');
        $emp_personal->employee_gender=$request->get('empl_gender');
        $emp_personal->employee_child=$request->get('empl_child');
        $emp_personal->employee_religion=$request->get('empl_religion');
        dd($emp_personal);
        $emp_personal->save();
        return redirect(route('emplisiting'));
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you sending user to the 'saveEmployeePersonal' from 'submitEmployeeBasic' function or, will the user come across a another form where you collect emp_farther_name etc ?

Comment: I'm sending employee id to saveEmployeePersonal to save in employee_id as foreign key to access it's information like emp_farther_name  etc. That's why i need to save id but i don't know the method.

Comment: I just need to pass created employee id to saveEmployeePersonal function and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values can be passed to route like bellow

```
$emp_id = $employee->id;
return redirect()->route('emplisiting')->with(compact('emp_id'));
```

the value can be access like $emp_id in the redirected place.

Comment: And from redirected place how i can pass to saveEmployeePersonal function back to controller?

Comment: use hidden input field and use employee_id as the value of that